# Wordpress - AMP Error | CSS syntax error in tag 'style amp-custom' - saw invalid at rule '@import'

Tags: php, css, wordpress, amp-html

I'm having trouble understanding the reason for this error inside Google Webmasters.

CSS syntax error in tag 'style amp-custom' - saw invalid at rule '@import'

[image: AMP Error]

I've tried locating the custom-amp css file with no luck... I've also tried to see if there was any custom code written inside the AMP plugin... with no luck.

Has anyone seen this before?

The affected URL is here: [Recipe Here](https://www.fatforweightloss.com.au/recipe/keto-guacamole/amp/)

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `@import` is blocking, so its at the top of the list of don'ts. move it out into a `<link>`

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer - Go to Appearance -> AMP -> Design -> Custom CSS - This was manually added in there ...for some reason!

Thanks, Everyone!